# ADJECTIVE_SATELLITE in JWI

Tags: java, wordnet, jwi

Sorry not technical but related to java AI from wordnet.
I am looking at the wordnet,
In that we have ADJECTIVE_SATELLITE ?

what is ADJECTIVE_SATELLITE? how is it different from ADJECTIVE.-Adjective satellite category.

2) SynsetType[] ALL_TYPES
when do we use this AllTypes?